# Simple point processes and the expected value

Tags: probability, point-process

When considering simple point processes, how is

$$P(t_{n+1} \in [t;t+dt]) = E[N([t;t+dt])]$$,

where $N(A)$ is the number of points in interval $A$ and $dt$ is the length of an infinitesimal interval. My argument is that it's because we are considering simple point processes - a.k.a there is either zero or one point in an infinitesimal interval. Is that true? If so, I'm feeling that I'm missing something in my argument. I think my question is still *why* we can say that it's the expected value?

And if it's all wrong, I hope I can get another explanation :)

Comment: I agree it's a different question, but it appears to be about exactly the same issue: namely, how to understand an "infinitesimal" interval.  There's a fundamental difficulty here, because the chance of a point lying in any infinitesimal interval is zero.  And that's exactly what your other question looks like it's trying to ask about.  I therefore would like to suggest you settle on a single best formulation of the issues you are pondering and edit your original question to focus on it.

Comment: My question is, why we can rewrite the probability function to be the expected value? My suggestion was, because there can't occur more than one point at the same time (since we only observe simple point processes), hence the same goes for a infinitesimal interval. However, I want a deeper explanation to since I can't provide it. The idea is specifically about why we can write is an expected value when considering simple point processes. it's not specifically about the infinitesimal interval. I hope this made it more clear?

Comment: Where do you get this equality? Do you have a reference? What does $dt$ mean? In the limit ($dt \to 0$) I imagine that these quantities go to zero. If it is not the limit then equality seems false (I imagine that the righthand side - the expectation of the number of events - can be above 1, while the lefthand side - a probability - must be below 1 by definition).

Comment: What is the meaning of $P(t_{n+1} \in [t;t+dt]) = E[N([t;t+dt])]$, what is $t_{n+1}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

If a random variable only can take the values 0 and 1 the expected value is equal to the probability of getting 1:

E(X) = 0*P(X=0) + 1*P(X=1) = P(X=1)

Together with the fact that it is a simple process and appropriate limiting arguments get you heuristically to the result you state.